# How to save multiple objects as .Rdata files with purrr

Tags: r, purrr

I have a list of objects in my R envir and I would like to save them as correspondent `.Rdata` files. I know how to save them individually, but **I would like to do it iteratively with `purrr`** (e.g. using `map` or `walk`?). I tried several times and I always get an error.

```
# Example dfs 
my_mtcars <- mtcars
my_orange <- Orange
list_dfs  <-  list (my_mtcars = my_mtcars, my_orange = my_orange)

# Individually I would do: 
saveRDS(object = my_mtcars, file = paste0("my_mtcars", ".RDS"))

# Here is one of my [WRONG] attempts
n <- 1:2 
purrr::walk2(.x = list_dfs, .y =n,  ~saveRDS(.x, file = paste0(names(list_dfs[n]), ".RDS")))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think better option would be to use `imap`/`iwalk` here which passes the data (`.x`) as well as name (`.y`) to the function.

```
purrr::imap(list_dfs, ~saveRDS(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".RDS")))
```

With `iwalk` -

```
purrr::iwalk(list_dfs, ~saveRDS(.x, file = paste0(.y, ".RDS")))
```